# How do the base number of stars impact the odds of acquiring that character?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

Different characters seem to have various number of stars to start. These include characters that haven't been unlocked yet. You can see this when looking at the Bronzium Data Card. There's a large section on the bottom of the screen listing the possible characters that can be acquired and they all range between 1 and 4 stars.

How does the number of stars impact the odds of acquiring one of these character cards?

Related: [How likely is it to pull a character from data cards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257684/how-likely-is-it-to-pull-a-character-from-data-cards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it, from the page I linked in my answer on that other question: http://www.swgohcantina.com/is-it-worth-it-to-spend-money-on-the-chromium-data-cards/

Essentially 2* and 3* are more common than 1* and 4*, but there's not really enough data to make hard conclusions about the exact rates.  However I would expect 7.5% each for the former two and 5% each for the latter two, or maybe 6% and 4% (with 75% going to non-characters).  That's for Chromium cards.

As for Bronzium cards, I haven't seen anything that has enough data to even begin to figure out the drop rates.  A 10% chance at a character is quite low to begin with so it's harder to pick out the star breakdown within that.

**Update:** I've been tracking my character drops from Bronziums for the last 6 months or so since I posted this answer.  Within an overall drop rate of about 2% of Bronziums, I got:

- 26x 1* characters
- 12x 2* characters
- 1x 3* character

I think I pulled a 4* character before I started tracking, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense. All of the 1-star characters are actually nameless grunts and, intuitively, should be the most common. So, I wonder if we simply need to wait for a larger dataset, or if there's a documented answer somewhere else.

Comment: From the perspective of the gambling model these F2P games have, it's important that the occasional "good" rewards aren't watered down in order to keep people trying for them.  So you could say that having 2&3 mixed with the occasional disappointing 1 and extra bonus 4 is most intuitive.  Besides, the game does not follow what you're suggesting elsewhere -- Dooku has two level 1 hard modes for shards, versus the Jedi Knight Guardian who has only one level 3 HM, for example.  The distribution in the PvP games and Store is even more odd.  More data would be great though!

Comment: I'm not sure character shards earned through the campaign is really a good comparison. Yes, Dooku has some available early on, but you also need a whole lot more of them (50) before you can unlock him because of his star rating (3), than you do with a 1 star grunt (10 shards).

Comment: @Ellesedil The same argument applies in reverse -- it's far easier to get Dooku to 4+ stars than it is for JKG, via those shards.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not concerned about promoting characters, simply unlocking them. Having said that, I'd like to think most players are also only concerned in unlocking characters. Promoting characters is a problem for "later". In either case, we're starting to drift away from the scope of the question.